# Koa-Cookie throwing "cookie is not a function"

Tags: cookies, koa

I am trying to follow the [instructions here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-cookie), and my code looks like this...

```
import Koa from "koa";
import cookie from "koa-cookie";

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const app = new Koa();
app.use(cookie());
```

But when I try running I get...

> TypeError: cookie is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing like this?

```js
import * as cookie from "koa-cookie";
```

This one below worked for me therefore above example should work too

```js
const Koa = require("koa");
const {default: cookie} = require("koa-cookie");

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const app = new Koa();
app.use(cookie());
app.listen(port);
```